# I want to populate a textbox in asp.net using xml data? can anybody help on this

Tags: asp.net

I am creating a aspx form and for that i need to add a textbox on which related data automatically get available for the user. i have data in form of xml, but i don't know how to do it?

Comment: What have you tried to do so far? Can you show us the code you have? What is the format of your XML? It's very hard to answer a question without some of those basic details about your problem.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<domcitycatelog>
<domestcity><ctname>DEL-Delhi|New Delhi (Delhi)</ctname></domestcity>
<domestcity><ctname>BOM-Mumbai|Mumbai (Bombay)</ctname></domestcity>
<domestcity><ctname>MAA-Chennai|Chennai (Madras)</ctname></domestcity>
<domestcity><ctname>COK-Kochi|Kochi (Cochin)</ctname></domestcity>
<domestcity><ctname>BLR-Bangaluru|Bangaluru (Bangalore)</ctname></domestcity>
<domestcity><ctname>HYD-Hyderabad|Hyderabad</ctname></domestcity>
<domestcity><ctname>CCU-Kolkata|Kolkata(Calcutta)</ctname></domestcity>\

Answer (score 0):

Load the XML into an XmlDocument. Iterate through it, pull out whatever data you want, and shove it into a string. Then, use the TextBox.Text property to pop it into the TextBox.